# Loop interrupt with an import module "interrupringcow" import error

Tags: python, interrupt

I have a problem with a downloaded module named interruptingcow
It is supposed to allow me to interrupt a loop after a set amount of time.
I have the latest version that i found installed with pip.

```
import time
from random import *
from interruptingcow import timeout
points = 0
error = 0

print('Today we will learn calculus! We will multiply random numbers from 2-10.\nPress Enter when ready!')
input()

try:
    with timeout(20, exception=RuntimeException):
        while True:
            XX, YY = randint(2, 10), randint(2, 10)
            print(XX, 'X', YY)
            if XX*YY == int(input('odgovor? > ')):
                print('GG! +1 point')
                points += 1
            else:
                print('Error! The real result is:', XX*YY)
                error = 1
                break
except RuntimeException:
    print('Your time is UP!')

print('Your score is:',points,'Thanks for playing! Press enter when you want to finish!')
input()
```

I think the problem is with the version of python? but i dont know how to fix it. Any ideas?
RuntimeException is underlined in the program, that is probably one of the errors, the other one is this:
ImportError: cannot import name 'GeneratorContextManager'

I looked at interruptingcow code and one of the imports is:

```
from contextlib import GeneratorContextManager
```

Thank you guyz in advance!

Comment: [Add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27775810/edit) the complete exception traceback to your question. Also, add which Python version you're using.

Comment: John gives a better solution below. As to why your error occurs: `interruptingcow` is at fault for using an undocumented class that is private to the module. See [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue10859), which shows `GeneratorContextManager` has been [renamed ](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f374e4e6d04b/Lib/contextlib.py#l34).

Comment: So i also tried to rename the import in interuptingcow from
from contextlib import GeneratorContextManager
to
from contextlib import _GeneratorContextManager
and just to be safe i evain tried:
from contextlib import __GeneratorContextManager
cause i thought that is what you are sugesting with [renamed] post...
non of which work

Comment: No no no: don't try and fix a broken module, particularly not by using undocumented private classes. Get rid of that cow module and use something else.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer :D The problem is this is the only thing i found until now that can do this on windows

Comment: Perhaps an [interesting read](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/22/how-not-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-computation-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this `interruptingcow` module at all, it's easy to set up a single timer to interrupt your loop with Python's built-in `signal` module:

```
import signal

def handler(signo, frame):
    raise RuntimeError

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(1) # seconds

while True:
    print 'zzz'
```

Just substitute your own `while True` loop and I think this will do what you need, without the extra dependency.

Comment: Hey thank you for the quick response! I probably should have said earlier i am using windows :D so this is not a viable solution. SIGALRM does not exist on windows and signal.alarm is also avaliable on unix not windows. Sorry if i messed something up.

Comment: But this module uses SIGALRM, perhaps that’s the issue then?